# Final rendered image is completely transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am rendering in view-port mode using cycles with GPU rendering but the problem is not there:

[image]

But when I am rendering a final render, it calculates everything and after some time, it gives this empty result. Why?

[image]

[image]

When I am rendering a big scene, it calculates everything and says that there is not enough memory on GPU. But I have 2GB of GPU memory.

Comment: That usually means you are out of memory. 2GB can get eaten up quickly, especially with lots of textures and geometry.

Comment: please answer my first question ?

Comment: That is my answer to your first question

Comment: Here is the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9FnFhTHyZQvNnV2ckxTdzh3anM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Samir gandalf3 Is correct, 2GB of can be used very fast depending on the size of your textures, and other things on the scene, plus the usage of your own monitor screen if you have only one GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you don't see anything when you render is because your **[Active Camera*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Camera)* is set to something different than the camera (in this case is set as the Area light).

Select your camera, make it active and your scene will render correctly.

You can do this two different ways:

Selecting the camera in the scene section of the properties window.

[image]

Or selecting your camera in the 3D viewport and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>
(or on the view menu->Cameras->Select Active object as Camera)